# React Redux: Updating Component on Multiple Dependent Props

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a react component, let's call it `Documents`. In this component I need to load multiple pieces of dependent data using `fetch`. I am using redux thunk for these async redux actions that perform data fetching.

So the component looks like this:

```js
interface Props {
  comments: Entity[];
  documents: Entity[];
  users: Entity[];
  getComments: Function;
  getDocuments: Function;
  getUsers: Function;
}

export class Documents<Props> {
  public async componentDidMount(props: Props){
    // is this the right lifecycle method for this since
    // it does not really need to change state
    const { documents, users, comments, getDocuments, getUsers, getComments} = props;
    if(!documents || !documents.length){
      await getDocuments();
    } else {
      await getUsers(documents.map(d => d.username));
    }
    getComments(documents, users); // dependent upon both users and documents
  }
  public render() {
    // render documents, users, and comments
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Documents);
```

Here I need to look at the documents before I can load users. And Both users and documents before I can load comments. What's the best approach for handling this in react. My `render` function will load small sub-components responsible for rendering these data but I don't want them to be connected components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to accomplish it with a functional component/useEffect hooks:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-varahamihira-kpssd?file=/src/Documents.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!documents || !documents.length) {
      getDocuments();
    } else {
      getUsers(documents);
    }
  }, [documents]);

   useEffect(() => {
    if (users) {
      getComments(documents, users);
    }
  }, [users]);
```

Comment: I am not using local state though. I just need the component to be re-rendered every time the store is updated _but_ while loading these related data properly.

Comment: I think I was able to accomplish it with a functional componet/useEffect hook (see edited answer); I'm not sure if its possible with a class component since it seems like an anti-pattern. Your thunk should be configuring all the data before it even gets to the component.

Comment: This is much more closer to how it should behave. I had been using class components this whole time, but this implementation with function components looks much cleaner. Thanks!